# Can I set up a TV in MODx to be dynamically gernerated by the user?

Tags: modx

I have a website that has a video archive page. My client wants this page to archive all his youtube videos. I created a TV called [[*addVideo]]. My issue is this. I need to set it up to where he can add videos whenever there is a new one (about once a week). I would like to add a function that would allow him to "add a new video" and dynamiclly duplicate the TV that I have created. I really don't want to create 50 separate TVs (how many videos he has now) and then have to go in and create more TVs throughout time. Is there any way to do this? I really don't even know where to look for references on this, I have been searching for about a day or two now and can't find anything.

It's built in Revo 2.2.7, I need it in a TV becasue I have it set up to where all he has to do is copy and paste the embed code in the TV and that code gets put into a mobile responsive div, that's why I can't just have him add them to the content field. Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated. I know there has to be something that I can do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should think of a custom manager page, where he can add entries (in this case videos)
You can use migxdb for that.